# Creating shaded areas for distances in the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, distance

I need to show my clients what 'zone' they live in (how much they will pay depending on how far away they are from my business).  I want to use Google Maps to give them a view of what roads/towns/cities/etc. are in what zone.  I was going to make some kind of definable barrier of sorts that would emanate from the center point.

I would have it so one barrier line showed where it was `x` miles away from the center point, another barrier would define areas `y` miles away, another defining areas `z` miles away, and so on and so forth.

I've never used the Google API and I'm only slightly good at Javascript...  What is the best path to take here to learning how to do this... or... even better... how would I do this?

Thanks for helping!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create polygons on the map and set the fill shading opacity such that it is slightly transparent.  When you layer concentric circles over one another, you'll see the shading change slightly.

I wrote a series of posts on how to use the maps API for Google, Bing, and MapQuest that you might find useful.

http://www.onesadjam.com/search/label/mapping

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation on google maps javascript api V3. I sense that you will be creating polygons - specifically look at how to do that. In the API, you can create a circle polygon, with options such as the center and radius, making your job very easy.